# System function is not working in C when the command contains ".."

Tags: c, linux, command-line, system

This is my code:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    system("getent passwd {1000..60000}");

    return 1;
}
```

I believe the ".." present in the command is causing the problem cause the program runs properly for other commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`system` does not run your *normal* shell. It instead **always** runs `/bin/sh`. From [`system`(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html):

> ### DESCRIPTION
>
> The `system`() library function uses `fork`(2) to create a child process
>              that executes the shell command specified in command using `execl`(3)
>              as follows:
>
> ```
>           execl("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", command, (char *) NULL);
> ```
>
> `system()` returns after the command has been completed.

Usually `/bin/sh` is a shell that does not understand `{1000..60000}`. To run bash or zsh you need to do something like

```
system("/bin/bash -c 'getent passwd {1000..60000}'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer to your question about system(), but may be useful to you:

```
#include <pwd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main() {
  struct passwd *p;
  while (NULL != (p = getpwent())) {
    printf("id=%d name=%s\n", p->pw_uid, p->pw_name);
  }
  endpwent();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: and filter on `if (p->pw_uid >= 1000 && p->pw_uid <= 60000)`